# Keeping selected options in php

Tags: php, forms, select

I have a dropdown select form that I need to make it so it stays the same option everytime I save.

So what I want is when I select an option from the dropdown, it stays the same when I've submitted the form and come back to the form another time.

https://hastebin.com/zafoxexoja.vbs

I've tried things all over google but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: store selected value in session

Comment: How do I do that...

Comment: you want to selected option selected everytime when user reload or back to come thata page right?

Comment: So pretty much this is the dropbox for how much time a package should last for.

I want it so everytime I come back to it, its the same as what I last set it to.

Comment: depend on session time

Comment: I dont understand. Im so bad at PHP and rarely know anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143551/discussion-between-ahmed-ginani-and-trifletower).

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session will help you for tha. you should try it. it will help you.
Below is your main page like index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<select id="editlength" name="editlength" class="form-control">
    <option value="1 Day" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '1 Day') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>1 Day</option>
    <option value="2 Days" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '2 Days') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>2 Days</option>
    <option value="3 Days" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '3 Days') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>3 Days</option>
    <option value="4 Days" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '4 Days') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>4 Days</option>
    <option value="5 Days" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '5 Days') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>5 Days</option>
    <option value="6 Days" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '6 Days') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>6 Days</option>
    <option value="10 Days" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '10 Days') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>10 Days</option>
    <option value="1 Week" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '1 Week') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>1 Week</option>
    <option value="2 Weeks" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) &&$_SESSION['editlength'] == '2 Weeks') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>2 Weeks</option>
    <option value="3 Weeks" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '3 Weeks') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>3 Weeks</option>
    <option value="1 Month" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '1 Month') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>1 Month</option>
    <option value="2 Months" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '2 Months') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>2 Months</option>
    <option value="3 Months" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '3 Months') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>3 Months</option>
    <option value="4 Months" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '4 Months') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>4 Months</option>
    <option value="5 Months" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['editlength']) && $_SESSION['editlength'] == '5 Months') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>5 Months</option> 
</select>
```

Javscript for ajax calling put it on your main page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editlength').on('change', function() {
      var val = jQuery("#editlength").val();
      $.ajax({
            url: "store_editlength.php",
            data: { editlength: val },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                // here no need of response
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

store_editlength.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['editlength']) && $_POST['editlength'] != '') {
 $_SESSION['editlength'] = $_POST['editlength'];
}
?>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have multiple plans/packages much means its the same select for all of them :/

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the `selected="selected"` inside the option for which you want the default selection like:

```
<option value="5 Days" selected="selected">5 Days</option>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unp0Lkom/)

Comment: I want it to be set to the same as what the user sets it to so it doesn't change everytime I reload the page. Its for a purchasable package and that option is how long the package lasts for. I want it so when I'm changing the dates, It says on the one last selected because every time I go to set them it resets the option.

Comment: Put `selected="selected"` inside a condition in which yo have to test the the option value against user given value

Comment: Sorry that makes no sense to me.

Comment: ```<option value="9 Months" <?php if($editlength == '9 Months') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>9 Months</option>```

Would this work, and just do this for the rest of them?